# Tag-info on Ignored tag more wiki detail

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags

The detail of [ignored-tags](/questions/tagged/ignored-tags) says:

> For each Stack Exchange site, logged in users can specify "Ignored
>   Tags" in their Preferences and directly from the Question list pages.
>
> Questions with these tags are then dimmed or removed entirely
>   (depending upon another preference) from question lists.

Could someone please update the 'depending upon another preference' and specify what that other preference is, because I don't know what it is and it annoys the *^&$&^* out of me that something that is supposedly 'ignored' is actually more prominent as it's 'greyed-out'.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the tag wiki to describe where the preference to hide ignored tags is, and include a screenshot. Now the tag wiki reads as:

> For each Stack Exchange site, logged in users can specify "Ignored Tags" in their Preferences and directly from the Question list pages.
>
> Questions with these tags are then dimmed or removed entirely (depending upon another preference shown on `users/preferences/<user id>`) from question lists.
>
> [image: screenshot]