# Do the mandatory tags cover all options?

Tags: discussion, meta

There are four mandatory tags for question on the meta. However, I don't feel my last question really fitted any of them.

[Tag-info on Ignored tag more wiki detail](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159605/tag-info-on-ignored-tag-more-wiki-detail) isn't a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), or a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and it's not intended for [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), it doesn't really feel exactly [support](/questions/tagged/support)-y to me.

Which tag should I have chosen? The question is asking for existing content to be expanded and clarified.

I suppose it's clear that this is a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) question.

Comment: I'd call it "support" personally, but "discussion" is pretty much the catch-all tag

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to me.

Somebody with enough power needs to change the text. And text changes are feature requests, although minor ones.

**Roadmap:**

- If something is different than you expect: [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
- If you want something changed on the site: [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)
- If you want help with something related to the site: [support](/questions/tagged/support)
- If you want to discus an idea or a problem with other users: [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)
- If you want something else:  fine, but meta is probably not the right place.

Comment: Or [tag:support] as you'd need help with functionality of the site..?

Comment: The first one might be better off as "If you spot what you think is unintended behavior".